# How do I import a downloaded font into the Phonto app?

Tags: applications, fonts

I am trying to import a font that I downloaded from http://dafont.com site into the [Phonto](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.youthhr.phonto) app. I am using WinZip on my PC. I have the HTC One phone. I have no clue what to do.

Answer (score 1):

You should follow [the developer's step-by-step instructions](http://phontogra.ph/phonto_font_android).

To summarise, if you downloaded a zip file, first unzip it (using any zip file app) to get to the .ttf or .otf file, then click that file to open it in Phonto, which will add the font.